# What is the difference between a void function() and a void ClassName::function() in C++?

Tags: c++, function

What is the difference between them? Are they both one-per object? (beginner question)

Comment: Any particular context you want to attach to this? Do you mean appearing within a class declaration or outside of a class namespace? (I would hope the latter is obvious).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The void function can be called without an instance of any specific class... i.e. just call...

```
function()
```

For `ClassName::function()` you need to call it on a specific object of type `ClassName`:

```
ClassName my_class;
my_class.function();
```

When called, `ClassName::function()` will have a hidden implicit function argument `this`, which can be used inside the function body.  It is a pointer to the `ClassName` object on which `ClassName::function` has been invoked.  You can also access other class members.

Another related difference is that you can take a pointer to `function()` and call it at any time, whereas when you take a pointer-to-member-function to `ClassName::function()` you'll also need a specific `ClassName` object at the time you want to run the function.

Comment: a static member function is very similar to a free function.

Comment: ... but has the at-times-very-handy benefit of access to class-private members (both functions and variables) without requiring friending. (+1 btw)

Answer (score 3):

A namespace scope function can be called from anywhere without a object:

```
int foo();

void bar() {
  int x = foo();
}
```

A member object needs an instance to be called, which is implied within the context of another member function:

```
struct B {
  int foo();

  int fred() {
    if (true) { 
      return foo(); // OK, local object implied
    }
    return n; // member function can also access member variables
  }

  static int george(); // static members can be called without instances!

  int n;
};

void baz() {
  B b;
  int x = B::george(); // static class members don't need instances.
  int y = b.foo();     // member function on object OK
//int z = foo();       // XXX: this wouldn't compile
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void ClassName::function()
```

is call to a function inside your class. **member function**. and should be called by using object of your class. while,

```
void function()
```

is just a function and can be called without object.